# Number of roots of $p_n-\lambda p_{n-1}$ where $p_n$ are orthogonal polynomials

Tags: functional-analysis, polynomials, roots, orthogonal-polynomials

> Let $(p_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ be the orthonormal sequence of polynomials associated to a tempered weight $w$ on an interval $I$ (so that for example, $\deg(p_n)=n$). Show that $p_n-\lambda p_{n-1}$ has $n$ distinct roots in $I$ for any real $\lambda$.

I'm stuck at how to prove this.

My attempt at a proof:
Let $l_n:=p_n-\lambda p_{n-1}$
and $r_1,..r_k$ be the roots of odd multiplicity in I. 
Let $q=(t-r_1)...(t-r_k)$ . Then $deg(q)=k≤n$. Note that $l_nq$ is either nonpositive or non negative. Hence $<l_n,q>\neq 0$. Since $l_n\in \{p_0,p_1,..,p_{n-2}\}^{perp}$. This implies that $deg(q)≥n-1$. This is where im stuck. Any helps or hints?

After this I have to show that the roots of $p_n$ and $p_{n-1}$ are interlaced. Any hints for that?

Comment: Are these polynomials with real coefficients?

Comment: I think the claim is false. Take $I = [-1,1]$, $w=1$, and $p_0 = 1$, $p_1(t) = t$. Then $p_1-\lambda p_0 = t-\lambda$ has exactly one root $\lambda$, which is not in $I$ for $|\lambda| > 1$. For $\lambda = 0$ the claim is true, though.

Comment: The polynomials are not arbitrary they are associatedwith the weight

Comment: What do you mean? I specified a weight in the example. And answer my first question.